# Why am i getting bar.addEventListener is not a function

Tags: javascript

```
const navSlide = () => {
    const bar = document.querySelectorAll('.bar');
    const nav = document.querySelectorAll('.nav_links');

    bar.addEventListener('click', () => {
        nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
    })
}
navSlide();
```

Comment: what does `const bar = document.querySelectorAll('.bar');` return?

Comment: Because bar is not an element but a collection of element. You have to iterate through allthe elements having this class.

Comment: if you want to access first item of bar collection simply write bar[0].addEvent.... (becuase bar is an collection not a single element)

Answer (score 1):

`querySelectorAll` returns a list, not a single element.

You might consider something like

```
const navSlide = () => {
const bar = document.querySelectorAll('.bar');
const nav = document.querySelectorAll('.nav_links');

 bar.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelectorAll('.nav_links').forEach((item) => {
      item.classList.toggle('nav-active');
    })
  })
}
navSlide();
```

Answer (score 1):

`querySelectoAll` returns node list , so need to iterate over it too

```js
const navSlide = () => {
  const bar = document.querySelectorAll('.bar');
  const nav = document.querySelectorAll('.nav_links');

  bar.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', () => {
      toggleClassVal()
    })
  })
}

function toggleClassVal() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.nav_links').forEach((item) => {
    item.classList.toggle('nav-active');
  })
}


navSlide();
```